# css inline-block with aligned center

Tags: html, alignment, css

I want a div that have same width as content which is done by `display: inline-block;`
but when I use this,`text-align: center` not working anymore.
so my content just go left and inline-block apply to it.
like this:

```
#div1 {
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
left: auto;
text-decoration: overline underline;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
}
```

it doesn't center the text of div anymore.
how I can get both effects of this two?

Comment: Please make a JSfiddle rather than posting a plain request.

Comment: Please post a complete code example here.

Comment: Can you please post some code or a demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the property  text-align:center to any other element, and use that element inside your div.

eg.

```
#div1 {
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
left: auto;
text-decoration: overline underline;
display: inline;
}
#p1 {
text-align: center;
}
```

and then

```
<div id="div1">
        <p id="p1">blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

That should work.

Comment: with a little edit it worked. onmouseover only triggred on text not whole width.but when you use `text-align:center`for _p1_ and 'display:inline' for _div1_ .I swaped them.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Getting same div is a work of `width` not `display`. When you use `text-align` this property, is applied to all the childs of the element.

For example, in

```
<div>
 <span>Text</span>
 Text
</div>

span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This will be applied to the text, not the span. This way, you will get the text aligned to the center, but the span will still be in its own location, `left` and just under the previous element as default.

To check whether `text-align` is being applied or not, you can try to check the property of the child in Developer Tools.

Jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/eKrNt/

You can see, that the property was applied to `div`, but instead of itself. It was the child, who got aligned to the center.

#### Your code:

```
#div1 {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 10px;
 left: auto;
 text-decoration: overline underline;
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
}
```

This is the clear answer, you are aligning the text inside this div to the center.

And the mouseover event must be somewhere in the function or script. Which is triggered on `hover` event or the same.

Comment: so how I can get a div in center with sme width as text in it?

Comment: For that, you can use `text-align` for the parent of the div lets say, `body` if its the only div. Or you can use `margin-left` and `margin-right` to some property.

Comment: I used `#dived{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}`as parent div but still it sticks to left.

Comment: That would work, when you're having `max-width` or `min-width` applied. Otherwise it will always stay to the left.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

in the parent div of the div you're trying to center.

Comment: just does the same thing.

Comment: sorry, try doing it to the actual div, not the parent div!